# CentOS - ipTables

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables

I have some questions about ipTables.

Is it possible to open all ports between 2000 and 6000 and then have 2245, 5435,5434 closed?

Is it possible to open some ports from a ip address? Eg. The only ip which can connect to our server through 2501 is 12.34.56.78

Is it possible to make different configurations for each fail over ip on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes it is but when writing IPTables rules it is a good idea to have a basic understanding on what is going on.

[CentOS IPTables HowTo](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables)

the howto there is perfect for what you are looking to do as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: meaning do all the leg work lol ;-)

Comment: All that is needed is just a copy-paste of the relevant information, just enough to answer the question. While the link to the source is good, your answer might become invalid due to [linkrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkrot).